# php change variable value dynamically after input text is typed

Tags: php, dynamic

I have one input box and I want to dynamically change variable value after text is typed in input box, but without pressing any button, only on text change.
For example:

```
Input box= $5
$text= input box value * 2
```

Anyone have idea how to do that?

EDIT: I know that I must use JavaScript, but I'm not good at it and I don't know how to write code.

EDIT2: I have this table:

```
<tr>
 <td>Mogući dobitak:</td>
 <td colspan='2'>" . $dobitak . "</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Ulog:</td>
 <td><input type='text' id='ulog' name='ulog' size='10' value='1' ></td>
 <td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Uplati'></td>
</tr>
```

So, after I enter value (default is 1) in input box (id='ulog') I want to change variable &dobitak.
Lets says that for this case input box value=$dobitak (I will add *2 later).

Comment: Are even read any of answers ? your edit means that you didnt understand any of them right. please read them, and try searching  in google about AJAX

Comment: I tried your code and it without success.

Comment: try a little search and come back

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly in PHP, because it only runs on the server; i.e. it has no idea when the user interacts with the webpage. Instead, you can use an AJAX approach. It would use client side scripting (e.g. JavaScript) to detect when the text changes, and then send a request to the server. The server processes the data and returns a response.

It's important to note though that this can't change a variable in a PHP script which is already running. It can only supply data at the start of a script.

Answer (score 0):

use ajax call to the server which fires with every textchange event

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with only PHP because it works on server side, not client side.
So you must use javascrpit for intercept this action. I think it's better.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server sidde scripting language, It creates a HTML and then terminates, and it has no Idea what is going on in client side after generating the html. and it will response, only if a request is sent to it.
for sending a request after an event in HTML, you must use ajax like this :

### HTML & jQuery

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>

<input type='text' id="text" onblur="change()" />
<script>
function change() {
    var text = $("#text").val();
    $.post('1.php',{text:text},function(e){
        $("#text").val(e);
    });
}
</script>
```

### 1.php

```
<?php
if($_POST['text']){
    die($_POST['text']." --- changes"); //or whatever changes that you want to do
} 
?>
```

it addes ' **--- changes**' to the end of input value on input's **blur**, you can make any changes that you want.

Comment: what do you mean NOT WORKING ? show the exact code that you tried in you question